# Interaction term in Lagrangian implying photon has no antiparticle?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, antimatter

I read that the QED Lagrangian interaction term ($-q\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu$) implies that while electron-positrons come in pairs, a photon does not need to form in a pair (and hence it does not have an antiparticle / it’s antiparticle is itself). In what way does the interaction term imply that? I assume it has to do with there being $\bar{\psi}$ and $\psi$ for the fermion field and only $A_\mu$ for the photon field, but how exactly does that lead us to postulate no antiphotons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QED Lagrangian must be hermitian, so one can say
$$\big(\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi A_\mu\big)^{\dagger}= \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi A_\mu, $$
and this implies that $A_{\mu}$ is a real-valued field: $A_{\mu}^\dagger=A_\mu$.
Thus, the photon does not have its anti-particle (i.e., consider the mode decomposition).

Also, the photon field has no U(1) charge
$$\big[Q,A_\mu \big]=0,$$
so naively it does not have the particle/antiparticle distinction that is classified by $U(1)$ charge.

Comment: The Q in the commutator refers to the electric/U(1) charge, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: I have read elsewhere that a photon is its own antiparticle. Is that wrong?

Comment: That statement is true, and not contradict to my statement. There is no distinction between particle and anti-particle.